# Manipulating data from json to reflect a single value from each entry

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

**Setup:**

This data set has 50 "issues", within these "issues" i have captured the data that I need to then put into my postgresql database. But when i get to "components" is where i have trouble.  I am able to get a list of all "names" of "components" but only want to have 1 instance of "name" for each "issue", and some of them have 2. Some are empty and would like to return null for those.

**Here is some sample data that should suffice:**

```
{
 "issues": [
    {
      "key": "1",
      "fields": {
        "components": [],
        "customfield_1": null,
        "customfield_2": null
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "2",
      "fields": {
        "components": [
            {
              "name": "Testing"
            }
          ],
        "customfield_1": null,
        "customfield_2": null
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "3",
      "fields": {
         "components": [
            {
              "name": "Documentation"
            },
            {
               "name": "Manufacturing"
            }
           ],
          "customfield_1": null,
          "customfield_2": 5
      }
     }
  ]
 }
```

**I am looking to return (just for the component name piece):**

```
['null', 'Testing', 'Documentation']
```

**I set up the other data for entry into the db like so:**

```
values = list((item['key'],
               //components list,
               item['fields']['customfield_1'],
               item['fields']['customfield_2']) for item in data_story['issues'])
```

I am wondering if there is a possible way to enter in the created components list where i have commented "components list" above

Just for recap, i want to have only 1 component name for each issue null or not and be able to have it put in the the `values` variable with the rest of the data.  Also the first `name` in components will work for each "issue"

Comment: What do you mean by "only want to have 1 instance of "name" for each "issue"".  Do you want to get rid of one or flatten it so that one "name" returns two values?

Comment: i want one to not be put into the list, so for each "issue" i only get one component name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do, assuming that we are working with a `data` variable:

```
values = [(x['fields']['components'][0]['name'] if len(x['fields']['components']) != 0 else 'null') for x in data['issues']]
```

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: This works but for completion sake, i would make the "//components list" part of the `value` variable this: `item['fields']['components'][0]['name'] if len(item['fields']['components']) != 0 else 'null'`

Answer (score 1):

in `dict comprehension` use `if/else`
example code is

```
results = [ (x['fields']['components'][0]['name'] if 'components' in x['fields'] and len(x['fields']['components']) > 0 else 'null') for x in data['issues'] ]
```

full sample code is

```
import json
data = json.loads('''{ "issues": [
{
    "key": "1",
    "fields": {
        "components": [],
        "customfield_1": null,
        "customfield_2": null
    }
},
{
    "key": "2",
    "fields": {
        "components": [
                {
                    "name": "Testing"
                }
            ],
        "customfield_1": null,
        "customfield_2": null
    }
},
{
    "key": "3",
    "fields": {
         "components": [
                {
                    "name": "Documentation"
                },
                {
                     "name": "Manufacturing"
                }
             ],
            "customfield_1": null,
            "customfield_2": 5
    }
 }
]
}''')

results = [ (x['fields']['components'][0]['name'] if 'components' in x['fields'] and len(x['fields']['components']) > 0 else 'null') for x in data['issues'] ]
print(results)
```

output is `['null', u'Testing', u'Documentation']`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to delete all but one of the names from the list, then you can do that this way:

```
issues={
 "issues": [
    {
      "key": "1",
      "fields": {
        "components": [],
        "customfield_1": "null",
        "customfield_2": "null"
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "2",
      "fields": {
        "components": [
            {
              "name": "Testing"
            }
          ],
        "customfield_1": "null",
        "customfield_2": "null"
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "3",
      "fields": {
         "components": [
            {
              "name": "Documentation"
            },
            {
               "name": "Manufacturing"
            }
           ],
          "customfield_1": "null",
          "customfield_2": 5
      }
     }
  ]
 }
```

Data^

```
componentlist=[]
for i in range(len(issues["issues"])):
    x= issues["issues"][i]["fields"]["components"]
    if len(x)==0:
        x="null"
        componentlist.append(x)
    else:
        x=issues["issues"][i]["fields"]["components"][0]
        componentlist.append(x)

print(componentlist)

>>>['null', {'name': 'Testing'}, {'name': 'Documentation'}]
```

Or, if you just want the values, and not the dictionary keys:

```
else:
    x=issues["issues"][i]["fields"]["components"][0]["name"]
    componentlist.append(x)

['null', 'Testing', 'Documentation']
```